# Exchange automated email import into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a ticket system that I would like to automate replies to go straight into the database by scanning the subject for a unique Ticket ID code. The mailbox is hosted with Office365 so Exchange/IMAP/POP3 can be used.

The ticket system is hosted on a Windows Server Operating System which the MSSQL database is installed on.

I was just wondering whether there is something that can be installed or whether a script could be ran to scan and import.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @HamiltonBlake Hey! Wow this question was opened a while back haha. What I would recommend doing would be using an inbound parsing service which is something that SendGrid or Mailgun (and other SMTP services) offer. So then you would have a domain/sub-domain that you want them to handle all incoming emails for. You point them towards an endpoint that's on the back of your application which you would then store into your database. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/inbound_email.html

Comment: Thanks very much!